# How to copy Xbox info from USB?

Tags: xbox-360

I have a USB that I formatted to use with my Xbox. It worked fine, used it for ages, no issue.

Now though, I have not used it on my Xbox for quite a while, so I was wondering if I might be capable of copying the data from the USB, onto my PC for temporary storage, then format the USB once more and use that as per normal?

(I do realize I can simply copy the data off the USB onto my Xbox, but that is a last resort at this point - Xbox is packed up etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe there is a hidden folder that the 360 makes on external storage devices. The path under Windows is (drive letter):\Xbox360\ and should contain a number of Data000* files

Note: This is the format for the Xbox 360. I am unsure if the same method is used for the Xbox One.

If you copy this folder off, you should be able to use your flashdrive normally, however other problems may arise from reformatting. Please also note: this is *not an official method*, as the only properly supported method is to copy your save files with the 360 itself.