# Tranferring from Xbox 360 using a USB Flash Drive

Tags: xbox-360

I transferred all of my content from one Xbox 360 system onto a USB Flash Drive. I no longer have the old Xbox 360 as the hard drive was wiped afterward and sold. I'm 100% positive I stored all of my stuff correctly onto the USB Flash drive and double checked multiple times that the content was listed on the USB flash drive.

Now, when I plug in the USB flash drive into my new Xbox 360, it is asking to configure and wipe out all the content on that USB Flash drive and will not allow me to access any of the content to transfer it on to the hard drive.

Can anyone help with this? What am I supposed to do? I've apparently lost EVERYTHING!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, if you have not already formatted the flash drive, you might be able to salvage the situation.

- First, you want to copy all the data from the flash drive onto your PC. [This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237247/how-to-copy-xbox-info-from-usb) has an answer describing how to do this.
- Second, insert the flash drive into the new xbox. ***Make sure you have copied the data off first before you continue***. Format as required.
- Finally, go back to your PC, and copy all the data back onto the flash drive.

This should hopefully solve your issue.